# Setting parameter variables using UrlRewrite in Struts 2

Tags: java, url-rewriting, struts2, tuckey-urlrewrite-filter

I'm using [Tuckey UrlRewrite](http://www.tuckey.org/urlrewrite/) in combination with a Struts2 application.

I'm trying to convert following URL:

`/promotions/abcdef-987` to `/dopromotions/detail` passing variable `id` as `987`.

**My rewrite rule is as follows:**

```
<rule>
    <from>^/(promoties|promotions)/([0-9a-zA-Z\-_]+)-([0-9]+)$</from>
    <set type="parameter" name="id">$3</set>
    <to>/dopromotions/detail</to>
</rule>
```

**And my Struts2 Action has following getters and setters:**

```
private Integer id;
public void setId(Integer id){
    this.id = id;
}
public Integer getId(Integer id){
    return id;
}
```

However, the variable never gets entered. When debugging, I can't find `id` anywhere in the parameter or attribute scope.

I've tried removing `type="parameter"`. This puts `id` in the attribute scope, but it doesn't get entered in my variable `Integer id`.

Comment: Just to mention: This method does work however watch out when using Maven. Maven only contains latest version 3.1 while the <set> methods are implemented as of 3.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the URL re-writer you are using, but you can achieve this sort of mapping with Struts2 alone.

Please refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4772737/hidden-features-of-struts-2-framework/4837917#4837917) about the `NamedVariablePatternMatcher`. You'll need the following constants set in your struts.xml:

```
<constant name="struts.mapper.alwaysSelectFullNamespace" value="false"/>
<constant name="struts.enable.SlashesInActionNames" value="true"/>
<constant name="struts.patternMatcher" value="namedVariable"/>
```

Then, map your action as:

```
<!-- you could also make /promotions a namespace and the action just "abcdef-{id}" -->
<action name="promotions/abcdef-{id}" class="...">
    ...
</action>
```