# Wildcard action mapping with dummy data in Struts 2

Tags: url-rewriting, struts2, seo, wildcard

I'm trying to map my Struts actions using wildcards.

Before, I used UrlRewrite Filter by Tuckey. But [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5430073/urlrewrite-struts2-setting-parameter-variables) changed my mind.

So here's my problem: My URL's look like the following:

- `www.example.com/promoties/category-123`
- `www.example.com/promoties/category-123/subcategory-456`

In these examples, the words `category` and `subcategory` are dummy data used to make the URL more relevant for search engines.

Now I'd like to ignore this dummy data, as I'm just interested in the (last) ID. In the first case `123` in the last case `456`.

**I've tried the following without success:**

```
<package name="promoties" namespace="/promoties" extends="struts-default">
    <action name="([0-9a-zA-Z\-_]+)-{id:([0-9]+)}$" class="CategoryAction">
        <result type="tiles">categorydetail</result>
    </action>
</package>
```

**Using following options in my `struts.xml`:**

```
<constant name="struts.enable.SlashesInActionNames" value="true"/>
<constant name="struts.mapper.alwaysSelectFullNamespace" value="false"/>
<constant name="struts.patternMatcher" value="regex" />
```

Has anyone tried this before? How would I go about doing this in Struts2?

Comment: Did you mean REST style?

Comment: No, I meant the parsing of URL. Not REST

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to use simple wild card mapping and regulate the validation of the id component to struts2 validation.  Here is an example which has been tested, but without validation.

**struts.xml** you'll see an action defined for *category-** and *category-*/subcategory-** in the second we'll just keep the second wild card.

```
<struts>
    <constant name="struts.enable.DynamicMethodInvocation" value="false" />
    <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />
    <constant name="struts.ognl.allowStaticMethodAccess" value="true"/>
    <constant name="struts.enable.SlashesInActionNames" value="true"/>
    <constant name="struts.mapper.alwaysSelectFullNamespace" value="false"/>
    <package namespace="" name="default" extends="struts-default">
        <action name="category-*" class="test.TestBean">
            <param name="id">{1}</param>
            <result>/WEB-INF/content/test/results.jsp</result>
        </action>
        <action name="category-*/subcategory-*" class="test.TestBean">
            <param name="id">{2}</param>
            <result>/WEB-INF/content/test/results.jsp</result>
        </action>
    </package>
</struts>
```

**test.TestBean** here I used a String but in your case you'll change this to int or Integer. You'll want to validate that we did get an integer using validation xml or simply implementing com.opensymphony.xwork2.Validateable.

```
package test;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

public class TestBean extends ActionSupport{
    //public to avoid get/set to make example shorter
    public String id;
}
```

/WEB-INF/content/test/results.jsp

```
<%@taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<html>
    <body>
        <h1>Wild Card Value</h1>
        id: <s:property value="id"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Example 1**
The url: example.com/category-helloBart produces...

Wild Card Value

id: helloBart

**Example 2**
The url: example.com/category-helloBart/subcategory-123 produces...

Wild Card Value

id: 123

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply. But using that approach, wouldn't I always have to type the words 'category' and 'subcategory' in my URL? It's exactly those words I want Struts2 to ignore.

Comment: Well then following the _action name="category-*/subcategory-*"_ form, could you not use:  _action name="*-*/*-*"_ now you'll want to capture {4}.  You'll also need  _action name="*-*"_ and capture {2}.

Comment: Hah! Almost perfect. Now it just tries to insert the 'id' value as a String as opposed to Long. Could you update your answer for future reference? I'll accept it in return :)

Comment: Well if you haven't figured it out, Struts2 type conversion is pretty smart just change "public String id;" to "public long id;" and you should be good to go.

Comment: This isn't working in `Struts 2.5.29`. Why so? Is there any work around for it?