# Struts2 : How to pass parameters in URL for result type dispatcher [default]

Tags: url, struts2

Of course parameters can pass by **URL** (**result type** `Redirect`/`Redirect Action`),
or pass to **action** by `@Action(params)` (`Static Parameters Interceptor`)

---

#### What I want

`id=123` must exist in **URL** after `validation errors` (`@Result(name="input")`)

```
/update?id=123
```

Similar to **RESTful** url pattern (`Struts2-rest-plugin` not be considered) :

```
/update/123
```

---

I use the `redirect-after-post technique` + `Message Store Interceptor` for success action, but it this can't be use for `input` after `validation errors`, because the data of action (include invalid data) will lost / restore to default.

Any solution / suggestion is welcome. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried wildcards to capture the data?

Here is a link to some struts2 documentation (reading it quickly I didn't think it was very useful): http://struts.apache.org/2.0.6/docs/wildcard-mappings.html

However if you follow though this post and solution you'll clearly see how to capture data from the URL (Although the poster of that question was more interested in excluding parts of the url, but it just makes the topic more complete): [Struts2 Wildcard action mapping with dummy data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5484392/struts2-wildcard-action-mapping-with-dummy-data/5505456#5505456)

It's possible that your issue is largely because of using "Redirect After Post".  There is little value for doing this in struts2.  In general this is better solved using a custom interceptor for what ever cross cutting concerns you have for those actions. If you're worried about double submissions the TokenInterceptor interceptor already addresses this.

Comment: Thanks! One of methods in `wildcard-mappings` (2.2+) should solved my problem. What disadvantages of using Redirect After Post (along with Message Store Interceptor)?

Comment: It might not be a big issue.  Simply there is no point in creating two actions which will form a chain.  You might as well just have one action, the only reason is if the fist action does some processing for a _group_ of actions that it will chain to.  Now that is the very definition of a "cross cutting concern" and is exactly what interceptors are designed to solve.  So if the first action is instead implemented as an interceptor, then there is no need for the message store interceptor.  Things should become more simple.